# Socket.io: What does 'true' mean in the socket.adapter.rooms object?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What does true mean in the object for example when you do log this `socket.adapter.rooms[socket.id].sockets[socket.id])` inside a socket.io connection you get `true`.

Here is an example of what I get when I: `console.log(socket.adapter.rooms)`

```
{
    PX6VQil1DihUzQjyAAAB: Room { sockets: { PX6VQil1DihQjyAAAB: true }, length: 1 },
    'room 1': Room { sockets: { PX6VQil1DihQjyAAAB: true }, length: 1 },
    'room 2': Room { sockets: { PX6VQil1DihQjyAAAB: true }, length: 1 },
    'room 3': Room { sockets: { PX6VQil1DihQjyAAAB: true }, length: 1 }
}
```

As you can see inside the sockets object `PX6VQil1DihQjyAAAB` has a value of `true`.

`PX6VQil1DihQjyAAAB` is the socket.id.

What does true mean? When will it ever be false?

Comment: did you ever find out?

Comment: @FabioaC No. Not yet.